# ¿Cómo pasar parámetros en un botón hacia el controlador?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

Tengo mi vista en MVC Net Core y tengo un botón "enviar". Tengo mi *controller* con este método y le quiero pasar un parámetro.

¿Cómo puedo hacer esto?

```
public ActionResult SaveOrder(string name)
{
   string result = "Error! Order Is Not Complete!";            
   return Json(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

La comunicacion del formulario con el ActionController es por Post o Get? supongo que por POST.
¿Podrias compartir el codigo de tu formulario?